# Angular - catch query string change in partial

Tags: angularjs

I have 5 menu items that call same partial view but with different QS parameters. Goal is to show same partial but load different data into grid, based on what menu user chose.
Menu code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#/workspace.html?id=1" target="_self">
        <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i><span>Credit Analysis</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#/workspace.html?id=2" target="_self">
        <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i><span>Approval</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The problem is controller only loads once and I cannot seem to catch query string change event again (I think because it is the same partial and Angular just does not reload controller when QS changes). So the URL changes but my event does not fire (below). What can be done?

```
MetronicApp.controller('WorkspaceController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout, $location) {
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {   
    // initialize core components
```

});

```
$scope.$watch('location.url()', function (url) {
    //alert('url change');
}, true);

var id = ($location.search()).id;
console.log(id);

switch (id) {
    case '1':
        $scope.inboxName = 'Credit Analysis';
        break;
    case '2':
        $scope.inboxName = 'Approval';
        break;
    case '3':
        $scope.inboxName = 'Documentation';
        break;
    case '4':
        $scope.inboxName = 'Workspace';
        break;

}
```

Comment: the quick and dirty way to fix this would be to put that switch code in a function and call it from inside the `$watch` function.  However, you probably should look into using a state machine like uiRouter to manage your states and views, instead of using switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch using a function, not a string with you desire:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $location.url();
}, ...
```

and also, after the change, you need to run your switch.

please look the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bO6n0QDjhtB2adCXNTJ4?p=preview)